# user field is not migrating over to my postgres from sqlite3

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

I am attempting to migrate over my sqlite3 to postgres and I'm running into a ton of issues. Now I'm having an issue where one of my user fields, '`receiver`' from my `instant_message` class is not found because it didn't migrate over to my postgres. How can I get it to migrate over correctly?

**error**

```
column dating_app_instantmessage.receiver_id does not exist LINE 1: ..."__count" FROM "dating_app_instantmessage"
```

[image]

**models.py/instant_message**

```
class InstantMessage(models.Model):

sender = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'sender',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
receiver = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name= 'receiver',on_delete=models.CASCADE )
conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
message = models.TextField()
date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Data creation",default=timezone.now, null=False)
viewed = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

For migrating SQlite to PostgreSQL
Follow these instruction:

1. `python manage.py dumpdata > db.json`
2. Change the database settings to new database such as of MySQL /
   PostgreSQL.
3. `python manage.py migrate`
4. `python manage.py shell`
   Enter the following in the shell

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models
import ContentType ContentType.objects.all().delete() python
```

5. `manage.py loaddata db.json`

Comment: Do I need to re-do everything as in delete my current postgres or can I start at the shell?

Comment: you should redo it, set back your django settings to use your sqlite again, dumb it into the json then start migrating as instructions said, after all it is a pretty quick process, takes like 5 min